# How does etherscan checks that the contract is ERC20, ERC721, ERC1155 standard implementation?

Tags: erc-20, ethers.js, etherscan

Suppose I created any ERC20 contract, how does etherscan recognise that the deployed contract is an ERC20?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect if an Ethereum address is an ERC20 token contract?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45364197/3873510)

Answer (score 1):

Metadata and ABI (Application Binary Interface):
The contract's metadata and ABI can provide information about its functions and events. Etherscan can use this data to determine whether the contract adheres to a specific standard. ERC20, ERC721, and ERC1155 contracts have well-defined function signatures and events that can be recognized through the ABI.